# Unable to update Audio in Nokia Lumia 625

Tags: update

I am unable to update the audio settings (equalizer) in my nokia lumia 625 device. It get downloaded but its not updating. When i click the audio in settings its not opening the menu even. Please help.

[image: list of problematic application]

Comment: This looks like you might need to get this fixed at a service centre, if you've already tried a factory reset, I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Seeing an absolute path in your settings seems like a more serious issue. As far as I can tell you have following the options:

- First, try a soft reset. It propably won't fix your issue, but it can be done quickly and perhaps you're in luck.
- After that, try another hard reset without restoring your backup. That fixes most of the problems resulting from WP8.1 updates.
- If that does not work, try restoring your OS using the [Nokia Software Recovery Tool](http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/NokiaSoftwareRecoveryToolInstaller.exe)
- If your problem still exists, you'll need help from Nokia / Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will try. N can u please help me in the procedure of hard reset.

Comment: Simply go to Settings -> about -> reset your phone. Remember, this will delete everything on your phone.